# What is the ssl address SSL for paypal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to make a php page to listen to Paypal's IPN. I've got it working in the sandbox, now I want to push it to prod. I cant find the right SSL request.

Here is a part of my php script:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com:443\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

The 2nd part of the question: how can I test it is working before a user buys something?

Comment: <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

Comment: That's the <form> checkout URL, not the IPN validation one. Small difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssl://www.paypal.com is the address to validate against.

Ensure /cgi-bin/webscr is the URI you're sending the POST to, and that it includes cmd=_notify-validate in the payload.

Additionally, set your HTTP version to HTTP/1.1. HTTP/1.0 requests will [not be supported anymore](https://www.paypal-notify.com/eventnotification/event_details_popup?eventId=2891) in the future.
You're already adding a Host header, so you're technically already sending HTTP 1.1 data.

Note that HTTP 1.1 may return chunked data, so if you're using fsockopen(), it needs to be able to handle that.
(cURL doesn't have this problem since it's a much more sophisticated HTTP library, as opposed to fsockopen which is purely a socket connection.)

Comment: thx for the answer! When I use the IPN simulator, I get INVALID when I dump the result in a file `fputs ($fp, $header . $req); file_put_contents('log2.txt', $fp);`. Does this means something is going wrong?

Comment: It means you're able to connect at least, so that's good. It does mean that the POST data you're sending doesn't match exactly what you received however. The data you send back for validation has to match exactly with the data received from PayPal in order for a 'VERIFIED' response to be returned.

Comment: And how do I check the data received from paypal so I can be sure I'm sending the same thing back?